# Spreading props in react as attributes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props, spread-syntax

I've read up on the es6 object spread operator and I've come across it being used in a react tutorial to spread props into a component. I can't understand how this is working though, for instance

```
const obj1 = { foo: 'bar', x: 42 };

const clonedObj = { ...obj1 };
```

I understand the properties of obj1 are just copied into a cloned object now but they are still in the form of **object properties**. So why when an object is spread in JSX do they change their form from object properties to **key/value attributes**? for instance if obj1 was spread in the below component it would be the same as separate attributes:

```
<Component {...obj1} >
<Component foo="bar" x={42}>
```

I can't find a reason for this, only some explanations that this is what React does. Is there a deeper reason to understand than just that. So specifically I'm wondering why the format changes from object properties to key value attributes? is it something that the React library is doing to convert? Otherwise I would expect object spreading format to be consistent wherever you use it i.e. staying in the form of object properties.

Comment: JSX is syntactical sugar that doesn't exist in non-Babel JS, so there's no perfect vanilla JS parallel. Think of a component in JSX as a function call, and the spreading part as spreading arguments onto a function argument list, and it's maybe a bit clearer. Ultimately, the "attributes" in JSX are turned into the `props` argument object since JS doesn't have named parameters.

Comment: Sure, I understand that JSX needs to be compiled into function calls, so does this mean that babel is converting the spread functionality of the object into the attributes then specifically for JSX elements?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. Yeah, Babel is converting the attributes on the component in JSX into a `props` object passed to the class component constructor or component function. Spreading is a way to unpack key-value pairs from an object into HTML-looking "attributes" that are converted into `props`. It's not React, it's JSX, `JSXSpreadAttribute` specifically.

Comment: I have tried to make the question clearer. I'm wondering why then the props object is spread, the format of the properties is changing from those in an object into key value pairs.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to answer that other than to say "that's how JSX designed it to be". Then again, objects _are_ key-value pairs, so the XML/HTML-looking key-value pair syntax of JSX isn't terribly different. Both of them wind up in `props`. `C({foo: "bar"})` and `<C foo="bar" />` are similar. If JSX designers wanted it differently, they could have used the syntax `<C {foo: "bar"} />` to pass props, then `<C {foo: "bar", ...whatever} />` would probably seem less odd to you, but they didn't. It's just syntactical sugar chosen based on what seemed most clear, I presume.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just wanted to know if there is any other deeper answer or some quirk to understand other than that is just how it is. It just feels odd as it's different to object spread as I know it already.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "spread operator". Spread syntax is part of object literals, another (different!) spread syntax is part of JSX element literals.

Comment: "*the format of the properties is changing from those in an object into key value pairs*" - you might as well wonder why the format of key-value attributes is changing into object properties when using React. The answer: it's all the same data structure behind the scenes, just different syntax between object literals and JSX.

Comment: Thanks @Phil I just wondered what is handling that representation from the object format into the markup format, it seems like it's done behind the scenes possibly by babel.

Comment: @jobe Nothing is converting object format into markup format.

Comment: "you might as well wonder why the format of key-value attributes is changing into object properties when using React." - That is something I have wondered about too.

Comment: @jobe JSX is transpiled by Babel into normal JS. When you write a transpiler, you can write any syntax you want and transform it into something else. The transpiler does these transformations for you that may seem magical. The whole point is you get to make up the syntax, so trying to reason about "why is it X?" is pointless--the designers just thought it was clearest that way. There's no deep meaning behind the syntax, it's just a sleight of hand trick.

Comment: @Bergi it is though isn't it, if both representations of that component example are considered equal? I feel I'm close to getting it but just missing something

Comment: thanks @ggorlen my understanding of the answer to my question then is that this is babel which is transpiling from the object to attributes and vice versa because that's how it's designed. Hope I got that right.

Comment: Sort of, Babel is the transpiler but JSX is the templating syntax that you write code in. These decisions with respect to "why does `...` spread to HTML attribute-like `foo="bar"`?" are JSX's design choices. See their [spec](https://github.com/facebook/jsx/blob/main/spec.emu).

Comment: @jobe Babel does no "*and vice versa*". It does not generate JSX attributes.

Comment: @jobe Have a looked at the transpiled output of JSX examples, with and without spread syntax? It may become clearer how JSX works when you understand what code is actually executed.

Comment: @Bergi you're right, it doesn't go vice versa, my bad. I have seen the transpiled output of react createElement calls but just confused how the 2 representations of props, as object properties and attributes are equal in JSX. I am doing more research on it.